# Is pork head on planned mosque spot really a problem?

Tags: pork, najis

Lately there was an excess: somebody placed [pork head on a spot planned for mosque](http://www.dw.com/en/dead-piglet-dumped-on-leipzig-mosque-building-site-inscribed-mutti-merkel/a-19075480).

Is this really a problem for building a mosque there? Or is this just some stupid superstition and this "obstacle" can be easily walked around? If it can be walked around, then can you say how?

Comment: This is a non-issue. There's no problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is haram (forbidden) to eat pork, as pig flesh is considered impure (najasat).

> Forbidden to you is... the flesh of swine...  -- [Qur'an 5:3](http://www.alim.org/library/quran/ayah/compare/5/3)
>
> O Muhammad tell them: I did not find in what has been revealed to me anything forbidden to be eaten by one who wishes to eat it, except the meat of an already dead animal, or running blood or the flesh of swine (pork) - for these are unclean... -- [Quran 6:145](http://www.alim.org/library/quran/ayah/compare/6/145)

Indeed the ground will be regarded as impure as a result of coming in contact with pig body parts.  However...

> And He it is Who sendeth the winds, glad tidings heralding His mercy, and We send down purifying water from the sky. -- [Quran 25:48](http://www.alim.org/library/quran/ayah/compare/25/48)

so...

> "We can just wait for the next rain or snowfall to cleanse the ground, so we do not fear from this side anything" --- [Abdel Azziz Qaasim Illi, spokesman for Switzerland's Central Islamic Council](http://edition.cnn.com/2011/11/12/world/europe/switzerland-mosque/) (discussing a related incident)

It's not a significant obstacle to building a mosque there.

If anyone is considering doing this, please don't harm animals;  pouring alcohol on the site would also make it impure, and have the same effect of (a) making Muslims feel unwelcome, and (b) momentarily obstruct the building of a mosque.

Comment: Would like to know where you found that the ground would be impure and you'd need rain or snow to clear it? In fiqh of Salah as long as the ground is dry you can pray.

Comment: I assumed there would be some wetness (such as blood) to the pig parts which leaks on to the ground.  Aside from being distasteful, I don't think it's enough for the blood to just be dry (which I deduced from e.g. praying while wearing pig leather being impermissible https://islamqa.info/en/177335).  There's a link in the quote in my answer.  I acknowledge that it's a news article, rather than a fatwa, and it's probably erring on the side of caution.

Comment: There's no consensus among scholars about pig being impure. What is clear is that one isn't allowed to eat the flesh as this is clearly stated in the Quran. Some madhabs if not the majority consider it impure, but they don't have strong evidences for that AFAIK. For example the shaifi'i madhab even considers the leather of a pig as impure even if it was tanned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can build mosque there, in case of any such things being found even in a built mosque, we just wash away NAJAS things and its clear. I don't know if it is necessary in this case, that mosque is not yet started to build there. But its even than better to wash that place where such thing was found.

### Allah Knows Best

Answer (score -2):

There is absolutely no problem, We can build mosque where ever we want, unless there is human graves under.